# Evaluate this integral using residue theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals, complex-numbers, residue-calculus

So we have $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\dfrac{x^2-a^2}{x^2+a^2}\cdot\dfrac{\sin x}{x}dx$. ($a>0$). I considered that we can just calculate the half of the imaginary part of 
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\dfrac{x^2-a^2}{x^2+a^2}\cdot\dfrac{e^{ix}}{x}dx$$

I considered taking a contour of big upper half circle with radius $R$, and $[-R,-\epsilon]$,$[\epsilon,R]$, with a small lower half circle with radius $\epsilon$. I estimated that the integral of upper large circle is zero as $R$ tends to $\infty$. However, I can not seem to estimate the integral over the small circle since the rational function part is quite tricky.

Can anyone help with this? Any hint would be appreciated!

Comment: The complex integral you wrote doesn't converge, so I think this is not the right way to approach the problem. (Much of the time it would be, but not here.)

Comment: The original problem evaluates from $0$ to infinity, is this the problem? I thought zero is a removable singularity so that I can extend it to the whole real line... I edited it, is it solvable now?

Comment: The singularity is removable in the original integral because of cancellations but not with the complex exponential. Now you have to come up with a contour that dodges the point $a i$...

Comment: @Ian It's the right way, one considers it as a principal value integral (if one doesn't punch a hole in $\mathbb{R}$ and add the semicircle before replacing $\sin x$ with $e^{ix}$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For functions $f$ with a *simple* pole at $z_0$, if we integrate along an arc $\gamma_{r,\theta}$ with radius $r$ and opening angle $\theta$, we have
$$
\lim_{r\to 0} \int_{\gamma_{r,\theta}} f(z)\,dz = \frac{\theta}{2\pi} \operatorname{Res}(f,z_0).
$$
See for example [How to rigorously justify "picking up half a residue"?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/319959) or [Integrating $\frac {e^{iz}}{z}$ over a semicircle around $0$ of radius $\epsilon$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/367626) for some details.

In other words, you will pick up half the residue at $z=0$ (as well as the residue at $ia$ in your integral.